# Viewing and Pausing JS, CSS, and HTML at the Same Time in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, developer-tools

I am trying to see what the JS, CSS, and HTML are for three different "states" in a slider I'm working with: the slider when the "active" class is applied to a slide, the slider when the "processing" class is applied to a slide, and the slider after the "active" class has been moved from one slide to another. I can see the CSS and the HTML for the first and third states easily just by looking at the elements in the inspector. I can also artificially apply the "processing" class to a slide by editing the HTML in the inspector to see what CSS is being applied to that class. However, I would like to be able to pause the JS, CSS, and HTML while the JS is executing (when it applies the "processing" class) to try to get a sense of what elements are being impacted (in addition to the slide). Is there a way to do this, and to view the given JS that is being applied at that moment, as well as the given CSS and HTMl that are being applied at that moment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'debug' JavaScript in the **Sources** tab, by either manually opening the file which holds the JavaScript you are trying to inspect (in the left hand column), or searching for it using the Dev Tools File Search.

You can then add a **breakpoint** to the line that you want the state to stop at, for example in your code you would select either the line where the `processing` class is added (before the line is executed and the class is added), or the one directly after (when the class has been added as the adding of the class has been executed), and then you can switch back to the **Elements** tab to see the HTML / CSS and inspect them.

Here's some more detailed information on the subject: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/